# asynctask class is not returning data to fragment

Tags: java, android, api, android-asynctask, retrofit

I am trying to fetch data from the API in the AsyncTask class and return the data to a fragment where the data is displayed in the RecyclerView. But the is data is always null and the fragment is always empty.

Take a look at my code.

My AsyncTask class:

```
public class EmployeesData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Employee>>{

List<Employee> data = new ArrayList<>();
EmployeesFragment emp;

public EmployeesData (EmployeesFragment emp){
    this.emp= emp;
}


@Override
protected List<Employee> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    RestService restService = new RestService();
    try {

        restService.getService().getEmployees(new Callback<List<Employee>>() {

            @Override
            public void success(List<Employee> employee, Response response) {

                data = employee;
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Toast.makeText(emp.getContext(), error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(emp.getContext(), ex.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    return data;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<Employee> data) {
    super.onPostExecute(data);
    emp.setList(data);
}
}
```

My Fragment:

```
public class EmployeesFragment extends Fragment {

RecyclerView rv;
List<Employee> employees= new ArrayList<>();
public EmployeesFragment () {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_employees, container, false);

    rv = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.emp_Rv);
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    fireYourAsyncTask();


   EmployeesRvAdapter adapter = new EmployeesRvAdapter (employees, getActivity());

    rv.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}

public void setList(List<Employee> data) {
    employees= data;
}

public void fireYourAsyncTask() {
    new EmployeesData(this).execute();
}
}
```

My RecyclerView Adapter:

```
public class EmployeesRvAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EmployeesRvAdapter.EmployeesHolder> {
List<Employees> employees;
LayoutInflater inflater;
Context context;
public class EmployeesHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView name, description;
    View container;
    public EmployeesHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_tv);
        description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description_tv);
        container = itemView.findViewById(R.id. item_root);
    }
}
public EmployeesRvAdapter(List<Employees> employees, Context c) {
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
    this.employees = employees;
    context = c;
}
@Override
public EmployeesRvAdapter.EmployeesHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.employees_rv_item, parent, false);
    return new EmployeesRvAdapter.EmployeesHolder(v);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final EmployeesRvAdapter.EmployeesHolder holder, int position) {
    Employees employee = Employees.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(employee.getName());
    holder.description.setText(employee.getDescription());
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return employees.size();
}
}
```

My RestService class:

```
public class RestService {
private static final String URL = "http://localhost:23000/";
private retrofit.RestAdapter restAdapter;
private EmployeesService apiService;

public RestService()
{
    restAdapter = new retrofit.RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(URL)
            .setLogLevel(retrofit.RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .build();

    apiService = restAdapter.create(EmployeesService.class);
}

public EmployeesService getService()
{
    return apiService;
}
}
```

My Employee Service interface:

```
public interface EmployeesService {
    @GET("/api/employees")
    public void getEmployees(Callback<List<Employee>> callback);
}
```

Can someone point where I am going wrong? I'd appreciate the help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you do not need an AsyncTask with Retrofit.

It could simply be this

```
private EmployeesRvAdapter adapter;

public void fireYourAsyncTask() {

    EmployeesService service = new RestService().getService();
    try {

        service.getEmployees(new Callback<List<Employee>>() {

            @Override
            public void success(List<Employee> employee, Response response) {
                employees.clear();
                employees.addAll(employee);
                adapter.notifyDatSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Toast.makeText(emp.getContext(), error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

It's cleaner looking if you did this, but that's up to you

```
public class EmployeesFragment extends Fragment implements Callback<List<Employee>> {
```

And by cleaner, I mean it's simply

```
public void fireYourAsyncTask() {
    EmployeesService service = new RestService().getService();
    service.getEmployees(this);
}
```

---

Regardless of where you add the data, this is not how you add to an ArrayList

```
employees= data;
```

That is reassignment. This is addition

```
employees.clear();
employees.addAll(data);
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked perfectly. Can you tell how can we store this data that we are fetching from API as cached data so that we can access it even when offline??

Comment: Short answer: SQLite, Realm database, or Firebase. Feel free post a separate question, though